# How can i show blackberry map in my application?

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gps

I want to display Blackberry map in my application in my application.Can anyone tell me how to display the blackberry map in my application ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since OS 4.5 there is net.rim.device.api.lbs.MapField which allows you to put Blackberry Maps in a field.

Another option is invoking the [Blackberry Maps application](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/How_To_-_Invoke_BlackBerry_Maps.html?nodeid=1366963&vernum=0).